# How to handle duplicate with clearer answer?

Tags: discussion

Understanding how to handle this flagging situation, I found this post issue about apache when troubleshooting for myself. [Trouble with Apache in Xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124599/trouble-with-apache-in-xampp-after-multiple-apache-installs).

The answer was very clear and well formatted, then in the comments I saw a link to a possible duplicate, [XAMPP on Windows - Apache not starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794829/xampp-on-windows-apache-not-starting%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B).

This is definately related and the answer is the same on both. So I flagged the first post as a duplicate to the second and I've been thinking if this was the right thing to do.

What if the latter question(which is newer) has a better formatted and clearer constructed answer then the older post?

But the older post was the first and is exactly the same as the newer question?

[Meta, How to handle a Duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled) I've Read this also but to me it's not clear in which category this falls.

> Questions may be duplicates if they have the same (potential) answers. This includes not only word-for-word duplicates, but also the same idea expressed in different words.

If i read this in the meta post it's definately a duplicate and should be handled that way. Is it even relevent to flag posts that are **x** years old?

It is not my intention to let the **meta effect** take this over(It probably will). But To me it's not clear how to handle in this situation.

Short Summary: As I See it the question that newer then the oldest question shouldn't have had an answer in the first place and just be set as a **duplicate**, but now it has an answer and the answer is exactly the same but nicer/clearer formatted(in my opinion). How to handle and what to do in this situation? Also taken into consideration that the oldest post has the most upvotes?

P.S: Not sure if this should have a *support* tag or not.